# Proper Use of Products in Link Token Request

Tags: plaid

Folks,

```
LinkTokenCreateRequest request = new LinkTokenCreateRequest()
        .user(user)
        .clientName("Plaid Test App")
        .products(Arrays.asList(Products.fromValue("auth")))
```

That Products enum has more options, and I tried providing one and a few more combinations into that method. However, most of the combinations retun 400 bad request response.

How exactly are we supposed to use "Products"? I want to make sure my users are able to connect any available product and/or bank. So looks like there' some gap (in my understanding). Fill it!

Answer (score 0):

The Products field indicates the specific Plaid API(s) you want to use. You can't allow users to connect "any product" because you have to actively integrate and pay for every Plaid API you're incorporating. For example, some Plaid APIs are specifically used for transferring money. If your app doesn't have funds transfer functionality, there's no reason to enable users for those APIs. Other Plaid APIs are used to verify users' income or assets for loan underwriting -- if you're not in the business of lending money, your app shouldn't use those APIs.

I'd recommend checking out [Explore by Use Case](https://plaid.com/docs/#explore-by-use-case) to see which products might map to your use case, and then reading more about the individual products for your use case to see which ones apply to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My platform uses many of the products auth, investments, transactions, liabilities,.... Sure I could ask the user to input the type of account, and create the token link accordingly but that would be a bad customer experience. I just tried this: If I init link with liabilities, transactions and investments, some institutions eg fidelity become deactivated from the link flow.

Comment: @ZiCode check out https://plaid.com/docs/link/initializing-products/ for details on why this is happening and some recommendations on how/when to initialize link. The short version is that you should only initialize Link with products you absolutely, definitely need for all users.